# Is there a proof that equal bandwidths have equal information-carrying capacity?

Tags: bandwidth, information-theory

Consider a continuous channel, band-limited to the $[f_{\text{min}},\,f_{\text{max}}]$ frequency window. A well-known statement says that, *as far as the dependence on the frequencies*, the information-carrying capacity of such a channel depends only on the bandwidth $B=f_{\text{max}}-f_{\text{min}}$, and *not* on the magnitudes of $f_{\text{min}}$ and $f_{\text{max}}$ separately. There are also dependencies on other, non-frequency-related variables (in particular, on the signal-to-noise ratio), but this question is about how the carrying capacity depends on the frequencies, while any and all other relevant variables are held fixed.

The rigorous underpinning of all statements connecting the information-carrying capacity and the bandwidth seems to be the [Shannon–Hartley  theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem): $C =  B \log_2 \left( 1+\frac{S}{N} \right),$ where $C$ is the information-carrying capacity and $S/N$ is the signal-to-noise ratio. However, in every (at least somewhat) careful statement and proof of the Shannon–Hartley I've seen (e.g., [this one](https://goo.gl/g0Vo8u); go one page up for the definition of $W$), the bandwidth always refers to the case when $f_{\text{min}}=0$. The reason seems to be that the proof relies on the Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem; and in the latter, the relevant bandwidth indeed always starts from zero, since that theorem is all about the rate of sampling. (This was what I had thought originally, but it turned out to be wrong. See **Update 1** below.)

Now, in order to be able to use a variety of frequencies for transmitting information, one typically (always?) resorts to some kind of a modulation scheme, say of the amplitude, or of the frequency, or of the phase, or something more complicated (QAM, ASK, PSK, OFDM...). And for each *known* modulation scheme, it can (presumably) be shown that, indeed, what matters (as far as the relation between the information-carrying capacity and the frequencies used) is the bandwidth around the carrier signal.

But perhaps this is just because we are not sufficiently clever. Perhaps there is a scheme, as yet undiscovered, that would manage to pack, within the same bandwidth, more information in a frequency band with $f_{\text{min}}>0$ than the Shannon–Hartley allows to be packed in a band with  $f_{\text{min}}=0$ (assuming the same signal-to-noise ratio in all cases).

Is there a proof that there could not be such a scheme? (As it turns out, probably yes. See **Update 2** below.) In other words, is there a proof that the bandwidth that enters the Shannon–Hartley can indeed be $f_{\text{max}}-f_{\text{min}}$ with $f_{\text{min}}$ any arbitrary positive number? Equivalently: is there some generalization of the Shannon–Hartley that allows $f_{\text{min}}$ to be any positive number? (Almost certainly yes. See **Update 1** below.)

**Update 1:** As pointed out by Omegaman and Peter K., the Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem in fact deals with the case of $f_{\text{min}}>0$ as well. As explained on the Wikipedia entry for that theorem,  "For example, in order to sample the FM radio signals in the frequency range of 100-102 MHz, it is not necessary to sample at 204 MHz (twice the upper frequency), but rather it is sufficient to sample at 4 MHz (twice the width of the frequency interval)." It would seem that this is the key to at least one way of answering this question.

**Update 2:** Jim Clay and especially Jason R. suggest the following line of reasoning: the theorem on reversibility states that "a reversible operation, transforming a signal into one or more waveforms, may be inserted between the channel output and the receiver without affecting the minimum attainable probability of error" (Wozencraft and Jacobs, p. 488, 1965). Now, for the purposes of the (sought-after generalized version of the) Shannon-Hartley, any sort of transformation of the signal to a channel with $f_{\text{min}}>0$ would have to be lossless, i.e. reversible. We would than need to prove the following theorem: "a reversible transformation from one channel, band-limited to $[f^{(1)}_{\text{min}},\,f^{(1)}_{\text{max}}]$, to another channel, band-limited to $[f^{(2)}_{\text{min}},\,f^{(2)}_{\text{max}}]$, preserves the signal-to-noise ratio if and only if the bandwidths of the two channels are the same, i.e. $f^{(1)}_{\text{max}}-f^{(1)}_{\text{min}}=f^{(2)}_{\text{max}}-f^{(2)}_{\text{min}}$." The required generalization of the Shannon-Hartley then follows.

Questions:

1. At least in W&J, the theorem on reversibility, at least superficially, seems to be given in somewhat different terms than those usually used to state the Shannon-Hartley. Is the theorem on reversibility really applicable to our attempt to generalize the Shannon-Hartley?
2. Does anyone know a proof (that does *not* invoke the generalized Shannon-Hartley) of the required theorem, i.e. that a reversible transformation preserves the signal-to-noise ratio if and only if it is between channels whose bandwidths are equal? In fact, one should be able to prove that, under a reversible transformation, $\big(1+\frac{S^{(1)}}{N^{(1)}}\big)^{f^{(1)}_{\text{max}}-f^{(1)}_{\text{min}}}=\big(1+\frac{S^{(2)}}{N^{(2)}}\big)^{f^{(2)}_{\text{max}}-f^{(2)}_{\text{min}}}$. It certainly *seems* that a statement like this should be provable directly, i.e. without invoking the Shannon-Hartley, but I don't have a proof yet.

It also occurs to me that a direct proof of the statement $\big(1+\frac{S^{(1)}}{N^{(1)}}\big)^{f^{(1)}_{\text{max}}-f^{(1)}_{\text{min}}}=\big(1+\frac{S^{(2)}}{N^{(2)}}\big)^{f^{(2)}_{\text{max}}-f^{(2)}_{\text{min}}}$ could be a key part of a nice complement to the usual information-theoretic treatment of the information-carrying capacity. For example, you could say that, since there is a strong intuition that a reversible transformation should not affect information content, the statement above suggests that the information-carrying capacity $C$ must be a function of $\big(1+\frac{S}{N}\big)^{f_{\text{max}}-f_{\text{min}}}$. Then we demand that the capacity of two channels combined must be the sum of the capacities of the individual channels, from which, by usual arguments, it then follows that the function must be a log.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a mathematician so I won't pretend to claim that this is anything like a proof, but at an intuitive level I think that the fact that you can deterministically transform baseband to passband and back again by multiplying with complex sinusoids implies that the two are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. However, isn't any lossless compression algorithm a counterexample to this intuitive principle?

Comment: @linguisticturn, generic data cannot be losslessly compressed.  data that shows certain patterns (like it's text) **can** be losslessly compressed.  but you cannot just take some arbitrary data stream and hope to losslessly compress it.

Comment: and i dunno that Jim's answer really speaks to the question.

Comment: Yes, I know, but *typicality* is part of the game here... The proposed intuitive principle is, "If there is any reversible map between two media, then their information-carrying capacities are the same." Counterexample:  consider e.g. the (uncompressed) .wav and the (losslessly compressed) .flac music files. Although one can "deterministically transform" one into another, they are not equivalent: a *typical* digitized piece of music in .flac will be only about half the size it would be in .wav.

Comment: Note that  "typicality" is part of the game in Shannon's treatment, too, though it is (of course) defined differently there, not to mention more rigorously.

Comment: @linguisticturn: Shannon's theorem assumes that the data being transmitted has already been perfectly compressed. If you transmit uncompressed data, you're wasting a fraction of the capacity of your channel.

Comment: Let me try to make my point a bit more directly. The principle proposed in the original answer is this: "if every signal in channel A can be deterministically transformed to a signal in channel B and vice versa, then the channels A and B have the same information-carrying capacity." Let's call this the "determinism principle" (DP). The original answer used AM modulation as an example, but in a principle like this, the precise manner of the transformation surely should not matter. All that should matter is that such a transformation exists.

Comment: I say that the DP, as stated, cannot be correct. Consider the set $S_{\text{B}}$ of all functions that are band-limited to frequencies $[0,\,B]$, and the set $S_{\text{W}}$ of all functions that are band-limited to frequencies $[0,\,W]$, where $B\neq W$. There exists a nice reversible mapping from $S_{\text{B}}$ to $S_{\text{W}}$ and back: if $b(t)\in S_{\text{B}}$, then let $\tilde{b}(k)$ be its Fourier transform; and similarly for $w(t)\in S_{\text{W}}$ and $\tilde{w}(k)$. The one-to-one transformation is: $\tilde{b}(k)=\tilde{w}(Wk/B)$.

Comment: So, if DP were true, it would follow that a channel band-limited to $[0,\,B]$ has the same information-carrying capacity as a channel band-limited to $[0,\,W]$ (of course, we assume that the signal-to-noise ratio is always constant). But we know that this is false. So the DP cannot be correct.

Comment: @linguisticturn the term "transform" in the answer is actually a "modulation", just a linear shift in the frequencies from base band $[0,f_b]$ to an arbitrary higher freqency interval say $[f_1, f_1+f_b]$. It is not a transform from one domain into another like the Fourier Transform you have pointed. Also note that bandwidths should be compared belonging to same domains. And finally channel information transmission capacity and data information compression are two different things. a WAV file or FLAC file have nothing to do with channel capacity.

Comment: @Fat32 First of all, I have abandoned the arguments that use data compression examples, as they seem to generate mostly confusion (possibly on my part as well).  

Second, as far as my latest argument: the transformation I introduced *does* stay in the same domain. It is a reversible map $S_{\text{B}} \to S_{\text{W}}$. It is defined as follows: to map  $w(t) \mapsto b(t)$, first find the Fourier transform $\tilde{w}(k)$ of $w(t)$; define $\tilde{b}(k)=\tilde{w}(Wk/B)$; finally, find $b(t)$ as the inverse Fourier transform of $\tilde{b}(k)$.

Comment: This map can be represented as $b(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-B}^{B}\,dk\,e^{ikt}\,\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\,d\tau\, w(\tau)\,e^{-i\frac{W}{B}k\tau}$, but I thought the previous description is more understandable.

Comment: As far as the nature of the transformation: yes, I know it's a modulation. I know that this sort of modulation does result in equal bandwidths having equal information-carrying capacity (provided you make it single-sideband modulation).

Comment: The issue is, does this fact, in and of itself, imply that there cannot be any completely *different*, as yet *unknown* sorts of schemes that would pack more information into some channel $[f_{\text{min}},\,f_{\text{max}}]$, for some $f_{\text{min}}>0$, than any currently known modulation schemes are able to? The original answer said that, yes, this fact in and of itself does imply that there are no more efficient schemes. Above, I tried to explain why I think that that particular argument does not work.

Comment: @linguisticturn sorry for mistaking that Fourier argument. Now coming to your claim of $b(k)=w(Wk/B)$ you seem to ignore noise from your model of the channel. Look at the formula, if there is no noise then S/N is inifite and capacity is infinite, and then you are right, you can transmit the most complex functions in the smallest possible bandwidth by the frequency-scaling you propose. But if you assume any nonzero noise, then such a scaling should I geuss change the signal to noise ratio of the channel and assumption of everything being the same will be violated.

Comment: And, to me you seem to be asking whether numbers in [7,9] are different than numbers in [13,15] Other than their magnitudes they possess the same properties. Why should a specific interval of frequencies possess different, information carrying, properties ?

Comment: @Fat32 The system is beginning to complain about the length of this discussion, and I don't have enough reputation to chat. If you agree, could you delete your first comment, above, and I'll delete my reply to that (as well as the present comment)?

Comment: @linguisticturn: I know this discussion went elsewhere after this, but your claim above about lossless compression schemes is missing the point. An uncompressed .wav file and a compressed .flac file will have different sizes, yes. However, the amount of *information* (in the "information theory" sense of the term) that they contain is identical. So, there is no contradiction.

Comment: @linguisticturn: With regard to your proposed mapping of a channel of bandwidth $W$ to a channel of greater bandwidth $B$, you have to consider the signal-to-noise ratio. When "stretching" your signal $s(t)$ out in bandwidth, the signal (which, if you define your reversible mapping carefully, shouldn't change in power) will occupy a larger bandwidth. That larger bandwidth will contain more noise power. So, if you keep the same amount of signal power, your SNR is poorer. You therefore don't get the expected boost in channel capacity by moving to the larger bandwidth $B$.

Comment: @Jason-R What you say is of course true. But remember what my purpose was: to explain why I don't think the original proposed answer is correct. So let me ask you: the original proposed answer tacitly assumed some general underlying principle; what was this principle? I say it is what I have called the DP (see the comments above); do you agree with me on that? If yes, do you think the DP is correct? If no, what then do you think *was* the underlying principle assumed?

Comment: @linguisticturn: Yes, I do believe the proposed principle is correct. I think your argument regarding scaling a proposed signal in the Fourier domain doesn't invalidate the principle for the reasons I described above. The principle being: applying a perfectly reversible operation to a channel doesn't affect its information-carrying capacity in any way.

Comment: @Jason-R Let me try a different tack. The principle as you formulated it is certainly a true statement. But: if pressed, how would you *justify* that principle? Keeping in mind what the very original question was, you are only allowed to use the case of Shannon-Hartley with $f_{\text{min}}=0$).

Comment: @linguisticturn: I don't have the time or information theory expertise to generate an actual proof. It just intuitively makes sense that a deterministic, reversible operation like a frequency shift can't affect a channel's information capacity. From a communication theory perspective, my go-to reference is Wozencraft and Jacobs, who invoke a "theorem of reversibility" in discussions of optimum receivers. They don't give a formal citation or proof for this, however. With that said, intuition is decidedly *not* a proof, but I'm an engineer, not an academic, so I'm willing to accept it.

Comment: @Jason-R Thank you. I have added an explanation of this reasoning to the text of the question (see **Update 2** at the end). Please let me know if you think there are any problems with what I wrote there.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably find the proof you need looking at Nyquist's [original paper](http://monoskop.org/images/2/2e/Nyquist_Harry_1928_Certain_Topics_in_Telegraph_Transmission_Theory.pdf).

In short, the analysis comes down to converting the information signal into a series of Fourier components, each a sinusoid of a given frequency and phase.  Equal bandwidths, by definition, accommodate an equal number of sinusoids of different frequencies regardless of their offset in the spectrum.

Shannon's contribution was to essentially figure out the limit on how many levels of those sinusoids can be distinguished in the presence of noise.

Comment: Thank you! As mentioned in another answer below, the following is found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem#Sampling_of_non-baseband_signals): "For example, in order to sample the FM radio signals in the frequency range of 100-102 MHz, it is not necessary to sample at 204 MHz (twice the upper frequency), but rather it is sufficient to sample at 4 MHz (twice the width of the frequency interval)." This must indeed be the key. After I have thought it through some more, I'll make the appropriate edits.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

> The reason seems to be that the proof relies on the Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem; and in the latter, the relevant bandwidth indeed always starts from zero,

[is incorrect.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem#Sampling_of_non-baseband_signals)

> A similar result is true if the band does not start at zero frequency but at some higher value, and can be proved by a linear translation (corresponding physically to single-sideband modulation) of the zero-frequency case. In this case the elementary pulse is obtained from sin(x)/x by single-side-band modulation.

Comment: Thank you! I discovered that very passage on Wikipedia a moment ago myself... "For example, in order to sample the FM radio signals in the frequency range of 100-102 MHz, it is not necessary to sample at 204 MHz (twice the upper frequency), but rather it is sufficient to sample at 4 MHz (twice the width of the frequency interval)."

This must indeed be the key. After I have digested it fully, I'll make the appropriate edit to the original question, and give your answer the vote.

Comment: @linguisticturn You're welcome!

Comment: @downvoter: what's the problem?

Comment: Incidentally, I'm trying to upvote this answer, but I think that, as a newbie, I lack reputation points for my upvote to take effect...  (I hope it's clear that it wasn't me who downvoted. :) )

Comment: @linguisticturn : Ya, I figured you weren't downvoting! :-) No worries; I have  a reasonable rep. I just get annoyed with anonymous downvoters when I'm pretty sure I have the right of it.